# Como puedo determinar cuantos strings hay en un array

Tags: c++, array, string

He creado un array de strings en c++ de la siguiente manera:

```
const char *a[]={"hola","mundo",....,"numeros"};
```

El problema es que no se cuantos elementos hay en ese array, ¿Cómo puedo determinarlo?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente? ¿Al número de elementos?

Comment: Exacto, ¿como hallo el número de elementos?